# WskSocketConnect -- possible memory corruption issue?

Tags: c, windows, driver, wdk

I'm trying to use the WinSock API from a driver to connect to another computer. The problem is that `WskSocketConnect` (and `WskConnect` if I go down that route) fail with `STATUS_INVALID_ADDRESS`. My code is:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4510)
#pragma warning(disable:4512)
#pragma warning(disable:4610)

#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wsk.h>

#pragma warning(pop)

const WSK_CLIENT_DISPATCH WskClientDispatch = {
    MAKE_WSK_VERSION(1, 0),
    0,
    NULL
};

WSK_REGISTRATION WskRegistration;

typedef struct _ASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT {
    KEVENT Event;
    PIRP Irp;
} ASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT, *PASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT;

extern "C" DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
extern "C" DRIVER_UNLOAD DriverUnload;
extern "C" KSTART_ROUTINE WorkerThread;
extern "C" IO_COMPLETION_ROUTINE SyncIrpCompletionRoutine;
extern "C" NTSTATUS WorkerThreadImpl();
extern "C" NTSTATUS InitializeAsynchronousOperationContext(PASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT Context);
extern "C" void FreeAsynchronousOperationContext(PASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT Context);
extern "C" void ReuseAsynchronousOperationContext(PASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT Context);
extern "C" NTSTATUS WaitForOperation(PASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT Context, NTSTATUS DispatchStatus);

NTSTATUS
    DriverEntry(
    __in PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
    __in PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
    );

VOID
    WorkerThread(
    __in PVOID Context
    );

VOID
    DriverUnload(
    __in PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject
    );

#ifdef ALLOC_PRAGMA

#pragma alloc_text(INIT, DriverEntry)
#pragma alloc_text(PAGE, DriverUnload)
#pragma alloc_text(PAGE, WorkerThread)
#pragma alloc_text(PAGE, WorkerThreadImpl)
#pragma alloc_text(PAGE, InitializeAsynchronousOperationContext)
#pragma alloc_text(PAGE, FreeAsynchronousOperationContext)
#pragma alloc_text(PAGE, ReuseAsynchronousOperationContext)
#pragma alloc_text(PAGE, WaitForOperation)

#endif

#define DATA_BUFFER_POOL_TAG 'wskt'

NTSTATUS
    DriverEntry(
    __in PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
    __in PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
    )
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    HANDLE threadHandle;
    WSK_CLIENT_NPI wskClientNpi;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    PAGED_CODE();

    DbgPrint("Loading");

    wskClientNpi.ClientContext = NULL;
    wskClientNpi.Dispatch = &WskClientDispatch;
    status = WskRegister(&wskClientNpi, &WskRegistration);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }

    status = PsCreateSystemThread(
        &threadHandle, THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        WorkerThread, NULL);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        WskDeregister(&WskRegistration);
        return status;
    }

    ZwClose(threadHandle);

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

    DbgPrint("Loaded");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

VOID
    DriverUnload(
    __in PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject
    )
{  
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);

    PAGED_CODE();

    DbgPrint("Unloading");
    WskDeregister(&WskRegistration);
    DbgPrint("Unloaded");
}

WSK_PROVIDER_NPI wskProviderNpi;
//CHAR Foo[10]; // padding
PCHAR DataBuffer;

USHORT htons(USHORT value)
{
    return value >> 8 | ((value & 0xff) << 8);
}

NTSTATUS InitializeAsynchronousOperationContext(PASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT Context)
{
    PAGED_CODE();

    Context->Irp = IoAllocateIrp(1, FALSE);
    if (Context->Irp == NULL) {
        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }

    KeInitializeEvent(&Context->Event, SynchronizationEvent, FALSE);

    IoSetCompletionRoutine(Context->Irp,
        SyncIrpCompletionRoutine,
        &Context->Event, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

void FreeAsynchronousOperationContext(PASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT Context)
{
    PAGED_CODE();

    IoFreeIrp(Context->Irp);
}

void ReuseAsynchronousOperationContext(PASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT Context)
{
    PAGED_CODE();

    IoReuseIrp(Context->Irp, STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL);
    IoSetCompletionRoutine(Context->Irp,
        SyncIrpCompletionRoutine,
        &Context->Event, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);
}

NTSTATUS WaitForOperation(PASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT Context, NTSTATUS DispatchStatus)
{
    PAGED_CODE();

    if (DispatchStatus == STATUS_PENDING) {
        KeWaitForSingleObject(&Context->Event, Executive, KernelMode, FALSE, NULL);
    }

    return Context->Irp->IoStatus.Status;
}

NTSTATUS WorkerThreadImpl()
{
    PAGED_CODE();

    NTSTATUS status;

    status = WskCaptureProviderNPI(
        &WskRegistration, 
        WSK_INFINITE_WAIT,
        &wskProviderNpi);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DbgPrint("WskCaptureProviderNPI FAIL");
        return status;
    }

    DataBuffer = (PCHAR) ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, PAGE_SIZE, DATA_BUFFER_POOL_TAG);
    if (DataBuffer == NULL) {
        WskReleaseProviderNPI(&WskRegistration);
        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }

    ASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT OperationContext;
    status = InitializeAsynchronousOperationContext(&OperationContext);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        WskReleaseProviderNPI(&WskRegistration);
        ExFreePoolWithTag(DataBuffer, DATA_BUFFER_POOL_TAG);
        return status;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN localAddr  = { AF_INET, 0, IN4ADDR_ANY_INIT };
    SOCKADDR_IN remoteAddr = { AF_INET, htons(7777), IN4ADDR_LOOPBACK_INIT };
    DbgPrint("%p", DataBuffer);

    status = wskProviderNpi.Dispatch->WskSocketConnect(&wskProviderNpi.Client,
        SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP,
        (PSOCKADDR) &localAddr, (PSOCKADDR) &remoteAddr, 0,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        OperationContext.Irp);
    // BUGBUG here, DataBuffer has changed since the previous DbgPrint()
    DbgPrint("%p", DataBuffer);
    status = WaitForOperation(&OperationContext, status);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        PWSK_SOCKET socket = (PWSK_SOCKET) OperationContext.Irp->IoStatus.Information;
        PWSK_PROVIDER_CONNECTION_DISPATCH connectionDispatch = (PWSK_PROVIDER_CONNECTION_DISPATCH) socket->Dispatch;
        ReuseAsynchronousOperationContext(&OperationContext);
        status = connectionDispatch->Basic.WskCloseSocket(socket, OperationContext.Irp);
        status = WaitForOperation(&OperationContext, status);
    }

    FreeAsynchronousOperationContext(&OperationContext);

    WskReleaseProviderNPI(&WskRegistration);
    ExFreePoolWithTag(DataBuffer, DATA_BUFFER_POOL_TAG);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

VOID
    WorkerThread(
    __in PVOID Context
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Context);

    PAGED_CODE();

    PsTerminateSystemThread(WorkerThreadImpl());
}

NTSTATUS
    SyncIrpCompletionRoutine(
    __in PDEVICE_OBJECT Reserved,
    __in PIRP Irp,
    _In_reads_opt_(_Inexpressible_("varies")) PVOID Context
    )
{    
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Reserved);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Irp);

    ASSERT(Context != NULL);

    if (Irp->PendingReturned) {
        KeSetEvent((PKEVENT) Context, 2, FALSE);
    }

    return STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED;
}
```

The call fails synchronously with `0xc0000141` (`STATUS_INVALID_ADDRESS`). I do have an application listening on that port on localhost and it's behaving the same way with a remote computer.

Any hints will be appreciated!

**EDIT** Now things are getting weirder. I updated the source code with my complete file.

I found the problem with `WskSocketConnect`: I was refactoring things and I tried to move the `WskCaptureProviderNPI` and `WskReleaseProviderNPI` to a different function and I started getting another error. That was weird, so I made my `WSK_PROVIDER_NPI` global -- it worked.

A bit later, I tried to send a message on that socket, but I was receiving two bytes of junk before it. After a few hours and some debugging messages, I noticed that the buffer address changes after the `WskSocketConnect` call. Now, the buffer address is a global variable, too, declared right after my `WSK_PROVIDER_NPI` struct. Adding some padding (search for "`Foo`" and "`WorkerThread()`") fixes it.

What now? I'm completely new to this, but it looks like the memory corruption is caused by the `Wsk` functions, especially since not much of my code gets to run between `DriverEntry` and that `WskSocketConnect` call. Any ideas?

This is on Windows 7 x64.

**UPDATE 2**
The compile warnings that I'm disabling at the beginning of the code are the following:

```
warning C4510: '_WSK_TDI_MAP_INFO' : default constructor could not be generated
warning C4512: '_WSK_TDI_MAP_INFO' : assignment operator could not be generated
warning C4610: struct '_WSK_TDI_MAP_INFO' can never be instantiated - user defined constructor required
```

I guess that compiling the file as C would fix them.

Regarding my `WSK_CLIENT_NPI`, the documentation for `WskRegister` does not mention that it should remain valid (like it does for the other argument) and the `echosrv` sample in the DDK does the same thing. Just to be sure, I tried making it global, but I am getting the same behavior.

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal compilable testcase. Minimal means "using only enough code to display the symptoms of your problem" and compilable means "can be compiled and run on our systems without filling in the blanks and making assumptions".

Comment: I added more information about my issue. I didn't know whether to include the build file or not and details about how I'm running it (a console application installing and starting the driver). I can provide them if it spares the time of somebody.

Comment: This is neither minimal nor compilable. Is there anything you don't understand from my previous comment?

Comment: Right, there were two lines of code at the end left over from the first version; I removed them and also removed some code that was running after the issue occurs. I left the cleanup code in.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest ignoring or disabling warnings, as warnings give a good indication of code that might not do what you want it to. Flaunt your warnings with pride and we'll help you remove them in a standard way. Make sure you show us which lines the warnings are on, as well as the warning messages. It seems to me as though you might be invoking undefined behaviour, and the warnings might highlight that.

Identifiers with leading underscores might also be troublesome, as this format is reserved for the OS API, compiler and standard libraries. Please rename _ASYNCHRONOUS_OPERATION_CONTEXT.

Which kind of pointer does %p tell DbgPrint (which uses printf format specifiers) to expect? void *. I suggest doing some casting, to handle the unlikely case that printf is causing problems.

It seems as though &wskProviderNpi.Client is meant to refer to the same object as &wskClientNpi. The problem here would be that wskClientNpi will be destroyed when DriverEntry returns, resulting in the "STATUS_INVALID_ADDRESS" error you mentioned (in a sort-of racy way). Have you tried putting the wskClientNpi declaration directly underneath the wskRegistration declaration?

Comment: I updated the question; it seems that extending the lifetime of that object makes no difference, same as removing the DbgPrint calls. I agree that my struct is badly named.

Comment: Very well. Have you tried writing a single-threaded version, and extending it by exposing multithreading to the parts that would be most beneficial?

Comment: The only thread I use here starts at the end of DriverEntry, runs and quits. I've done it this way to avoid calling `WskCaptureProviderNPI` -- which can block indefinitely -- in the DriverEntry function.

Comment: I tried it, anyway, and the only difference is that Driver Verifier (which I have enabled) does its job better and crashes on the `ExFreePoolWithTag(DataBuffer, DATA_BUFFER_POOL_TAG)` line because the pointer is corrupt.